# Angular 6 - Reactive forms and checkbox values

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My server sends me an array of condiments per detail item, I then need to send the selected values back as an array of strings.

I would like to overwrite the checkbox default values of true|false in a reactive form using formArray.

When the checkbox is checked, the string values in the form model get replaced by true, then when unchecked false.

This is what I have now:

Code:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
            condiments: this.fb.array([
                'KETCHUP',
                'RELISH',
                'MUSTARD',
                'MAYO'
            ])
         });
```

Template (Bootstrap 4):

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" formArrayName="condiments" *ngFor="let condiment of form.controls.condiments.controls; let i = index">
  <input [formControlName]="i" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck{{i}}">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck{{i}}">{{ condiment.value }}</label>
</div>
```

The result once KETCHUP is unselected:

```
"condiments": [
  false,
  "RELISH",
  "MUSTARD",
  "MAYO"
 ]
```

I would like to specify the value of the checkbox when unchecked to empty string and when checked to the initial value.

The idea is that when I submit the form, the server is expecting an array of selections.

Maybe I am approaching this the wrong way and I need to maintain 2 arrays?

Comment: what do mean by maintain 2 arrays? can you add your code in stackblitz.com